# Regular Expression without braces

Tags: c#, regex

i have the following sample cases :

- 1) "Sample"
- 2) "[10,25]"

I want to form a(only one) regular expression pattern, to which the above examples are passed returns me `"Sample"` and `"10,25"`.

Note: Input strings do not include Quotes.

I came up with the following expression `(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])`, this satisfies the second case and retreives me only `"10,25"` but when the first case is matched it returns me blank. I want "Sample" to be returned? can anyone help me.

C#.

Comment: So your possible formats are "some text value" or "[number 1,number 2]" - is that the case?

Comment: Can you clarify what your input looks like in general? Right now you could just match anything that isn't [ or ].

Comment: yeah. "Some text value" or "[text,text]" - when matched with the regular exp should return Some text value or text,text

Comment: And do you input include the quote symbols?

Comment: Input strings do not include Quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go, a small regex using a positive lookbehind, sometime these are very handy

**Regex**

```
(?<=^|\[)([\w,]+)
```

**Test string**

```
Sample
[10,25]
```

**Result**

MATCH 1

1. [0-6]   `Sample`

MATCH 2

1. [8-13]  `10,25`

try at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/tV6kH5/2)

---

if `"` is included in your original string, use this regex, this will look for `"` mark as well, you may choose to remove `^|` from lookup if `"` mark is always included or you may choose to leave it as it is if your text has combination of with and without `"` marks

**Regex**

```
(?<=^|\[|\")([\w,]+)
```

try at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/tV6kH5/3)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the below regex should help:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\w+|[[](\w)+\,(\w)+[]]$");
```

This will match multiple words, or 2 words (alphanumeric) separated by commas and inside square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

One Java example:

```
//          String input = "Sample"; 
            String input = "[10,25]";
            String text = "[^,\\[\\]]+";

            Pattern pMod = Pattern.compile("(" + text + ")|(?>\\[(" + text + "," + text + ")\\])");
            Matcher mMod = pMod.matcher(input);
            while (mMod.find()) {
                if(mMod.group(1) != null) {
                    System.out.println(mMod.group(1));
                }
                if(mMod.group(2)!=null) {
                    System.out.println(mMod.group(2));
                }               
            }
```

if input is "[hello&bye,25|35]", then the output is hello&bye,25|35